# Button click doesn't load first element of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am wanting the user to be able to click a button, then move through an array of quotes with each press of the *enter* key. What I currently have is the button click loading the array into the function and the *enter* key moving through each element of the array, but the problem is getting the first quote to display on the screen *with the initial button click*. I am needing the first quote to appear on button click. As it stands, the button click is only setting me up for the functionality to work.
Any attempt I have made to correct this has resulted in the function being called with each press of the *enter* key (which doesn't come close to what I am wanting as an end result).  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const quotes = [0, 1, 2, 3];

function runFunction(v){
  document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
      if ( e.keyCode == 13 && v.length > 0) {
          let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * v.length);
          let num = v[randNum];
          v.splice(randNum, 1);

          e.preventDefault();

          switch (num){
              case 0:
                  document.querySelector('.quote').textContent = "America will never be destroyed from the outside";                                   document.querySelector('.author').innerHTML = 'Abraham Lincoln';
                  break;
              case 1: 
                  document.querySelector('.quote').textContent = 'Imagination is more important than knowledge.';
                  document.querySelector('.author').textContent = 'Albert Einstein';
                  break;
              case 2:
                  document.querySelector('.quote').textContent = "Have no fear of perfection, you'll never reach it."
                  document.querySelector('.author').textContent = 'Salvador Dali';
                  break;
              case 3: 
                  document.querySelector('.quote').textContent = "We don't make mistakes, just happy little accidents.";
                  document.querySelector('.author').textContent = 'Bob Ross';
                  break;
          }
      } 
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="quote"> Quote </div>
<div class="author"> Author </div>
<button onclick="runFunction(quotes)"> Get Quotes </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets split your code into 2 functions:

1. `onEnter()`
   Here we will set the first quote, and add the event listener for <kbd>enter</kbd>
2. `setQuote()`
   The actual code that will set a new quote, and remove it from the list

Then we change the `onClick` to our new `onEnter` function: `onclick="onEnter()"`

Example:

```js
const quotes = [0, 1, 2, 3];

function onEnter() {

    // Set the first one
    setQuote();
    
    // Now add eventListener for ENTER key
    document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
      if ( event.keyCode == 13 && quotes.length > 0) {
          setQuote();
      } 
  });
}

function setQuote() {
  let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  let num = quotes[randNum];
  quotes.splice(randNum, 1);

  switch (num){
      case 0:
          document.querySelector('.quote').textContent = "America will never be destroyed from the outside";
          document.querySelector('.author').innerHTML = 'Abraham Lincoln';
          break;
      case 1: 
          document.querySelector('.quote').textContent = 'Imagination is more important than knowledge.';
          document.querySelector('.author').textContent = 'Albert Einstein';
          break;
      case 2:
          document.querySelector('.quote').textContent = "Have no fear of perfection, you'll never reach it."
          document.querySelector('.author').textContent = 'Salvador Dali';
          break;
      case 3: 
          document.querySelector('.quote').textContent = "We don't make mistakes, just happy little accidents.";
          document.querySelector('.author').textContent = 'Bob Ross';
          break;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="quote"> Quote </div>
<div class="author"> Author </div>
<button onclick="onEnter()"> Get Quotes </button>
```